# Issue in cloning slide with chart in ppt template in Open XML

Tags: openxml-sdk

Hi I am not able to clone my template slide with placeholders.I am getting error
"**Power Point Found a problem with content in ouputput.pptx.Power point can attempt to repair the presentation**" while open the output ppt file.

code is completely referenced from
https://blog.prowareness.com/2009/10/openxml-cloning-slides-that-have-charts/